# If $F_X(x), F_Y(y)$ are two CDF's for r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$, will $F_{X,Y}(x,y) < F_X(x) \cdot F_Y(y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

Tags: probability

If $F_X(x), F_Y(y)$ are two CDF's for r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$, if $X$ and $Y$ **are** independent, then:

$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X(x) \cdot F_Y(y)
$$

However, I am wondering more generally if

$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y) < F_X(x) \cdot F_Y(y)
$$

if $X$ and $Y$ are **not** independent or if it depends how the joint distribution is constructed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X=Y$ then $F_X(x)F_Y(x)=(F_X(x))^{2} <F_X(x)=F_{X,Y}(x,x)$ provided $F_X(x)<1$.

Comment: For cases not perfectly dependent, is there a general rule of thumb?

Comment: No. there is no reason to expect an inequalilty of the type you have come up with.